# Подскажите как спарсить информацию

Tags: php, html, парсер

Добрый день. Я хочу на своём сайте реализовать в меню пункт о рейсах самолётов, но для этого я решил спарсить информацию с другого сайта, http://avia-sng.ru/domodedovo-online.php.

Как можно быстро спарсить эту таблицу и поставить у себя? Я знаю лишь только то, что нужно использовать `preg_match` и в него поместить код `div`, который нужно спарсить. Я правильно понимаю? Если можно, покажите это простейшим кодом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

> Я знаю лишь только то, что нужно использовать preg_match и в него
>   поместить код div, который нужно спарсить.

Тому, кто вложил в вас эти "знания", нужно дать в лоб :) Парсить ваши страницы нужно HTML-парсерами, коих для PHP есть несколько. Выбирайте любой, пробуйте, будут сложности - обращайтесь. До того ваш вопрос ни о чём.

Answer (score 1):

С таким вопросом - к фрилансерам.
Парсер написать - это отдельный и не самый простой заказ.

Но алгоритм прост:
Загружаешь страницу --> Обрабатываешь её любым HTML-парсером --> В его дереве выбираешь нужную информацию --> Сохраняешь/выдаёшь информацию в удобном виде.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте [phpquery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/)  , всё очень просто.

## чуть подробнее

скачайте вот эту phpQuery библиотеку [здесь](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/list) и подключите,
убедитесь что у вас подключен curl,
далее :

```
include('phpQuery.php');    
$ch = curl_init('http:/site.ru/'); //необходимая ссылка
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$results_page = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch) 
$results = phpQuery::newDocument($results_page); //получаем результат
if(!empty($results)){ //Если ответ есть
//далее просто указываем нежный элемент следующим образом
$address = strip_tags($results->find('address')); //по тегу
$phone = strip_tags($results->find('.poct-cont-phone')); //по классу
$comment = strip_tags($results->find('#comment')); //по id
}
```

Comment: Ответы-ссылки здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: @TheDoctor а то что вы [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427947/Проблема-с-русскими-буквами-json-encode) ссылку оставили?

Comment: @bemulima, вы не понимаете разницу между ссылками в ответах и ответами-ссылками? На мете объяснят, здесь заниматься ликбезом не стоит.

Comment: Ссылки разрешены и приветствуются, но в ответе нужно чуть больше, чем ссылка. А то я бы на половину вопросов просто кидал ссылку в гугл с нужным запросом.

Comment: Я просто дал человеку ссылку чтоб он сам прочем и понял, как можно решить его задачу. До этого сколько видел таких ответов, и даже благодарили. А тут на тебе) Сегодня не мой день, все на меня кидаются) Сейчас пример добавлю

Comment: Это не ответ, а максимум - комментарий. Или поправляйте, или он будет удален.