# Проблема с русскими буквами json_encode?

Tags: php, json

Всем привет! Для начало перейдите по этой ссылке?
http://music.kamnedsoft.kz/api/get_category

Там возвращается json с русскими буквами, а результат кривой.

```
[{"id":"1","title":"\u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438","alias":""},{"id":"2","title":"\u0417\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0435\u0436\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438","alias":""}]
```

Код простой, получаю данные из БД и вывожу через json_encode

```
$data['category'] = $this->admin_model->get_category();
echo json_encode($data['category']);
```

Мне нужно уже получать нормальный готовый результат, т.к. планируюсь подключаться и парсить json удаленно с андройд приложения,? что скажите? есть какое нибудь решение которое не будет забирать ресурсы?

Comment: омг , *для начал**а***, андро**и**д, что скаж**е**те, какое-нибудь

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37998/%d0%9a%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-json-encode?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Непонятно одно - с чего автор решил, что результат "кривой" и что с русскими буквами есть хоть какая-то проблема.

Comment: Поставлил плюс, но вообще не является ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Читаем [ману](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).
В функцию вторым аргументом можно поставить [некие константы](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php). Например не кодировать многобайтные символы юникода: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` (решение Вашей проблемы).

Comment: Добавил второй параметр выдает кучу ошибок страшных!!! Фраймворк codeignither

Comment: Какие именно ошибки? Какая версия PHP?

Comment: Да их вообще не нужно конвертировать. А константа работает только начиная с 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

> Там возвращается json с русскими буквами, а результат кривой.

Результат нормальный:
1 - Русские исполнители
2 - Зарубежные исполнители

Answer (score 1):

Это абсолютно валидный вывод JSON. В JSON, чтобы обойти проблему с кодировками, принято кодировать все в символах ASCII-таблицы, заменяя юникодные символы на представления `\uXXXX`, соответствующие этим символам, таким образом достигается независимость от кодировки передачи данных, что мы и видим в этом примере. Андроид такой вывод должен нормально отработать (возможно, потребуются дополнительные флаги декодирования), иначе он вафел.

Вы смотрите сериализованные данные. Сериализованные данные не предназначены для того, чтобы их кто-то смотрел - они предназначены для передачи, и это абсолютно нормально, что их не прочитать.

Answer (score -4):

попробуйте так вывести:

```
$result = array( ... ); //ваш массив

echo preg_replace_callback('/\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/',
            create_function('$match', 'return mb_convert_encoding("&#" . intval($match[1], 16) . ";", "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");'),
            json_encode($result));
```

результат?

Comment: Что это?! Ваш код, даже если будет работать (в чём я сомневаюсь), будет работать неправильно, потому что у регулярки ошибки в обе стороны. Я уж молчу про доступность замыканий много лет как.

Comment: По крайней мере у меня работает и пока без ошибок.

Comment: Как ваша функция обработает "\\u0001" (экранированный обратный слеш)?